# Analyze if there are any errors on the whole page of the spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have a page with values from Column A through Z, with 20,000 rows.

And I wonder if any of the cells contain any errors. Is there any way to find this out through a formula?

I tried using the `=IFERROR(COUNTIF(A1:Z,"<>'"),"Contains errors")` and also `=IFERROR(COUNTA(A1:Z),"Contains errors")`

I figured that because it contains cells with formula errors, it would also return in error, but it disregards the errors and returns the number of nonempty cells.

What I would like to do is that if there is an error it would return something that I could put something like:
`=IFERROR(XXXX,"Contains errors")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Another:

=sum(arrayformula(if(iserror(A1:Z),1,0)))

Answer (score 0):

I just got it on my own, in a very simple way. It was my lack of attention, but I will leave the solution if anyone needs:

`=COUNTIF(IFERROR(A1:Z,"Contains errors"),"=Contains errors")`

If the sum is greater than zero, there are errors.